# Data not getting fetched from Oracle in PHP using WAMP Server

Tags: php, oracle, wamp, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to fetch data from Oracle in PHP on WAMP Server with the following code but, the data is not getting fetched, neither am i getting any error. But when i execute the same query on Oracle directly, i am getting the data. Also, with same connection parameters within the same php file, i am able to fetch data for another query

```
$server = "localhost";
$sid = "xe";
$user = "hrs";
$passwd = "hrs123";

$conn = oci_connect($user, $passwd, $server."/".$sid);
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    echo $m['message'], "\n";
    exit;

}
else{
}

$staffno = test_input($_POST['field1']);

if($staffno!='')
{
$exempquery="select stno as stno, nvl(ffname,'')||' '||nvl(lname,'') as fname, substr(gradep,0,1) as grd, nvl(decode(sex,'M','MALE','F','FEMALE'),'') as sex, to_char(birth_dt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as birthdt, to_char(sep_dt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as sepdt, to_char(ret_dt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as retdt, sepdes from emp_master  where stno='$staffno' and ((sep_dt<='31-03-2013' and ret_dt<='31-03-2013') or (sep_dt is null and ret_dt<='31-03-2013'))";


    $exempstid=oci_parse($conn,$exempquery);

    $exempchk=oci_execute($exempstid);
    $exemprow=oci_fetch_array($exempstid, OCI_BOTH);


    $name=$exemprow['FNAME'];
    $grd=$exemprow['GRD'];
    $sex=$exemprow['SEX'];
    $birthdt=$exemprow['BIRTHDT'];
    $sepdt=$exemprow['SEPDT'];
    $retdt=$exemprow['RETDT'];
    $sepdes=$exemprow['SEPDES'];
}
```

The database connection is working fine. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check if `oci_parse` returns false and display the content of `oci_error()` if it is the case. Some thing with `oci_execute`

Comment: Tried doing it, but nothing is getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

- Check your webserver log files for errors
- During development, you could do worse than add this to the top of the script to make sure errors are shown:

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  ```

  Remember to remove these where you put your script in productions
- Consider using a HEREDOC or NOWDOC for complex SQL statements, see [PHP 5.3 "NOWDOCS" make SQL escaping easier](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/php-53-quotnowdocsquot-make-sql-escaping-easier).
- Use `OCI_ASSOC` instead of the (default) `OCI_BOTH`.
- Before going too far, you MUST rewrite your SQL statement to use a bind variable because the way you concatenate `$staffno` into the statement is a [security risk](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) (and will affect performance & scalability).  I don't have your data, but something like this is the way to go:

  ```
  $exempquery="select stno as stno, nvl(ffname,'')||' '||nvl(lname,'') as fname, substr(gradep,0,1) as grd, nvl(decode(sex,'M','MALE','F','FEMALE'),'') as sex, to_char(birth_dt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as birthdt, to_char(sep_dt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as sepdt, to_char(ret_dt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as retdt, sepdes from emp_master  where stno = :staffnobv and ((sep_dt<='31-03-2013' and ret_dt<='31-03-2013') or (sep_dt is null and ret_dt<='31-03-2013'))";

  $s = oci_parse($c, $exempquery);
  if (!$s) {
      $m = oci_error($c);
      trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
  }

  $r = oci_bind_by_name($s, ":staffnobv", $staffno);
  if (!$r) {
      $m = oci_error($s);
      trigger_error('Could not bind a parameter: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
  }

  $r = oci_execute($s);
  if (!$r) {
      $m = oci_error($s);
      trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
  }
  ```

  You possibly want one or more bind variables for the date too, unless it really will never, ever change.